# Which IE6 is the newer one?

Tags: internet-explorer-6, version

I have two copies of IE:

```
Version: 6.0.2900.5512
Update Versions : SP3
```

and

```
Version 6.0.3790.3959
Update Versions : SP2
```

Which one is the newer one? T_____T

Comment: Why do you have IE6 in the first place?

Comment: Maybe because he's a developer and needs to test for IE6?

Comment: Ugh. http://hey-it.com/ .

Answer (score 12):

```
Version 6.0.3790.3959
Update Versions : SP2
```

That is the newest one.  Update versions usually refers to the Windows service pack.

Incase you were wondering how software versioning works with Windows/Microsoft (as you can tell if you have Visual Studio), see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1302230/patch-vs-upgrade/1302262#1302262) for details.

Comment: the version number is newer, but how do you know that SP3 doesnt include whatever was in the ".2900" to ".3790" maintenance build fix plus some more updates?

Comment: SP2/SP3 refers to the operating system.  It has nothing to do with the actual browser.

Answer (score 3):

6.00.3790.3959 is newer.

> Version: 6.0.2900.5512 Update Versions
>   : SP3

SP3 is referring to Internet Explorer 6 for **Windows XP SP3**

> Version 6.0.3790.3959 Update Versions
>   : SP2

SP2 is referring to **Internet Explorer 6 SP2** for Windows Server 2003 SP1 and Windows XP x64

[Released versions of Internet Explorer for Windows](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/969393/)

Comment: +1 Good explanation of how the noted SP levels integrate with the versions.

Answer (score 1):

Go with the IE Version: 6.0.3790 would be the newest.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at version number you should go with 6.0.3790.3959